# Unable to get new token using JWT method (C#)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to set up a method so each time my application is accessed it retrieves a new token using JWT.

I've ran through the docusign github examples but this is still newer to me so I am stuck unfortunately.

```
using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth;

public string getAccessToken(){
var apiClient = new ApiClient();

            OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken({clientID},
                            "{Impersonated User GUID}",
                            "https://account-d.docusign.com",
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jwtPrivKey"]),
                            1);

return authToken.access_token;

}
```

Exception Details: DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Error with response Body:

Comment: Thanks, but this site is used so rarely it will be needed. I am also going to include a check though to prevent it if the site is accessed more frequently but I feel this may be a site used only once every few months. Also the point is to avoid user interaction for token generation so I believe I am going the right way, thanks though.

Comment: I use the same code (for the most part) that you have here. The only difference I notice is my `auth path` does not include "https://` so it is only `account-d.docusign.com`. I would try removing that and seeing if that helps at all. Might be one of those magical things that doesn't make complete sense.

Comment: @dvo thanks! that was it, something so simple! post a reply with it and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create an envelope with no Sender name? For this case, use a "system signer" DocuSign user account such as "Membership Department".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar code to what you have. I ran into an issue when I was developing where my `auth path` variable could not include "`https://`". I have to use plain "`account-d.docusign.com`" instead.

Comment: stupid question which you don't have to answer but is there a way to create a document without requiring a signer name? if you don't know I can keep looking into it :)

Comment: @TheInexperiencedGamer I'm not sure. For all my cases, I have our user's name we are getting a signature for so I've never actually tried it without a name. I would recommend researching how to not provide one or insert some generic name like "Customer" or "Member".